# Multiple URLs in text file - BeautifulSoup Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a text file `urls.txt` in the same directory as my `script.py`

`urls.txt` has a list of multiple urls, one per line.

I am attempting to scrape all the urls in one shot and pull out the contents of a particular `div`

This `div` occurs multiple times on each URL

here is my script

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

with open('urls.txt') as inf:
    urls = (line.strip() for line in inf)
    for url in urls:
        site = urlopen(url)   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml")
        for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "vm-product-descr-container-1"}):
            print item.text
```

Instead of returning the contents from all the urls in `urls.txt` the script is only returning the contents from the last url in the list.

My script is not returning any errors, so I am not sure where I went wrong.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: @danidee you might have just edited the error out of his code ^^

Comment: @RobBenz, how does your accepted  answer actually answer your question, that would mean you had  a syntax error when you say you get the last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a small identation error:
Look at this block:

```
for url in urls:
    site = urlopen(url)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml")
    for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "vm-product-descr-container-1"}):
    print item.text
```

Change it to this one:

```
for url in urls:
    site = urlopen(url)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site, "lxml")
    for item in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "vm-product-descr-container-1"}):
        print item.text
```

This way the print will execute for each iteration in the inside for loop.

Comment: No, you'll have an indentation error with your answer